# React how to get value from a constructor

Tags: reactjs

React how to get the props value from a constructor to a method.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
}

handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
}
```

How access the props value inside the handleSubmit method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to `bind` the event handler in the constructor

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)

  this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
}

handleSubmit() {
  console.log(this.props)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialise state in constructor and then use that in your function.

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {data:'Hey'};
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}

handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    console.log(this.state.data);
}
```

Comment: using your example I get this: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of null

Comment: As far as i understood OP he wants to access `props`. Using the component state is not necessary for that.

Answer (score 0):

Simply access it via `this.props`. You need to bind the handler method to the correct scope:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
}

handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    console.log(this.props)
}
```

The answer of [Hemerson Carlin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46281265/675065) is basically the same, but with another approach on how to bind the method. I find my approach a bit more appealing since you don't need to explicitly write down the bind statement.

Comment: I get this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of null

Comment: code please (codepen, jsfiddle, plunkr or something else)